# HTML tag with attribute containing hyphen

Tags: python-3.x, angular-ui-grid

I have a requirement to generate HTML from python. For that I am using HTML module.
As I use angularJS in my application I have to add attribute like 'ng-controller' in div tag.(A attribute name that contain hyphen)
for example

```
<div ng-controller='myController'></div>
```

HTML module does not allow hyphen or any special character as a part of attribute name.

I tried a lot, But I am not able to find any solution. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: There's an example at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html#tags-with-difficult-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently checked HTML module there is raw_text() function which allow user to explicitly add HTML code.

```html
from html import HTML()
h = HTML()
h.raw_text('<div ng-controller="a"></div>')
```